# Parallel development of two versions in git , having some common commits

Tags: git, workflow, git-branch

Usually i am following the workflow as described here: [Git branch workflows](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Branching-Workflows)

But in a specific project i have 2 develop branches (v1 and v2). Master is currently v1 stable.

I will use sub branches in developv2 for features that ia am adding.

This is what i have

```
master (v1 stable)
developv1
developv2
```

also:

```
feat/v1/topic1
feat/v2/topic2
...
```

each if the feat are merged accordignly to the developvx branches.

But as v2 is taking time to complete i am correcting bugs in v1 that i want to exist in my current v2 development.

I am a little confused as how to approach this scenario.

Comment: You can cherry-pick commits back and forth using `git cherry-pick`, but actually sharing commits between different branches without merging them isn’t possible.